# Sonarlint-apex staticanalyzer code quality

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, salesforce, apex, sonarlint

I have installed the sonarlint in my eclipse IDE. But I am unable to scan my apex code.Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Any errors or messages you could share? What versions of the apps on what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

SonarLint embeds a set of code analyzers and may run later versions if it is [connected](https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) to a SonarQube server with a newer version of an analyzer. But it will not run analyzers that are not in its embedded whitelist of SonarSource analyzers. SonarSource does not offer an analyzer for apex, therefore you will not see SonarLint raise issues on such code.